# send more than 8 bytes over standard CAN Bus in STM32CubeIDE

Tags: stm32, can-bus, stm32cubeide

I want to send more than 8 bytes over standrad CAN Bus in STM32CudeIDE but I do not know how to do that: I am sending three floating point value where each floating point are 4 bytes. The first two floating point go well but when I try to send the third one, the thing gets in troble because we can not send more than 8 bytes.
I get the value for voltage, temperature and SOC from the function main_function(dev_address); and then send them to SendFloatsOverCAN();
here is my code;

```c
main_function(dev_address);
SendFloatsOverCAN(&hcan2, voltage, temperature, SOC);
HAL_Delay(500);
```

Here in the function I send the floating point values through CAN Bus:

```c
void SendFloatsOverCAN(CAN_HandleTypeDef *hcan, float voltageVal, float temperatureVal){
    TxHeader.DLC = 8;  // this specifies the length of the data that will be send //8
    TxHeader.ExtId = 0;  // since we use standard protocol we set it to zero
    TxHeader.IDE = CAN_ID_STD; // the IDE is the standard ID
    TxHeader.RTR = CAN_RTR_DATA;  // we send data not frame
    TxHeader.StdId = 0x102;  // this is the identifire, must check why 0x103
    TxHeader.TransmitGlobalTime = DISABLE;
    

    HAL_CAN_AddTxMessage(&hcan2, &TxHeader, TxData, TxMailbox);
}
```

Here In the receiving byte I receive them:

```c
float receivedVoltage;
float receivedTemperatuer;
float receivedSOC;

void HAL_CAN_RxFifo0MsgPendingCallback(CAN_HandleTypeDef *hcan)
{
   HAL_CAN_GetRxMessage(hcan, CAN_RX_FIFO0, &RxHeader, RxData); // data will be recieved from CAN_RX_FIFO0, the header will be stored in RxHeader, data will be saved in RxData

}
```

Suppose that other thing is correct configured. I know that it is possible to send more than 8 bytes over standard CAN Bus to devide deta in smaller chunk or send them one at a time but I do not know how to do that. Really appriciate if some can explain me with help av maybe with some lines of code to understand

I tried to send more than 8 bytes over standard CAN Bus but it does not work and I do not know how solve theh.

Comment: Your code is very confusing and badly formatted. If the blocks of code were in properly formatted and indented code blocks, they __might__ be easier to understand. But maybe not even then. Your `SendFloatsOverCAN()` function appears to take voltage and temperature parameters, but doesn't use them for anything.

Answer (score 0):

A quick websearch tells me: *In CAN standards its not possible to send more than 8 bytes of data. We can achieve that using CAN TP.*

[CAN TP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_15765-2) is another layer on top of CAN that enables sending more than 8 bytes per message. This is achieved (handled by the protocol) by chopping (segmenting) the payload into smaller chunks and then sending the chunks in standard sized CAN frames.

But for your basic task I see no need to go all the way and add another layer to it. Instead you could send one float and a type tag per CAN frame. This type tag could be 1=Voltage, 2=Temperature, etc.

```cpp
void SendFloatOverCAN(CAN_HandleTypeDef *hcan, float Value, unsigned char TypeTag){
  TxHeader.DLC = 8; 
  // More header stuff goes here

  // Pack the Value and Type Tag into TxData and send it
  // This is just an example assuming TxData is a byte array
  memcpy(Message, &f, sizeof(f));
  Message[4] = TypeTag;
  HAL_CAN_AddTxMessage(&hcan2, &TxHeader, TxData, TxMailbox);
}
```

TxData array would look like this:

| [7] | [6] | [5] | [4] | [3] | [2] | [1] | [0] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| res. | res. | res. | tag | float | float | float | float |